# Why is the "Variable used in Lambda expression must be final or effectively final" warning ignored for instance variables

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm studying java 8 streams and the only problem I have is understanding lambdas is why the effectively final warning in lambdas is ignored for instance(and static) variables. I can't seem to find any reference to it online, as most pages will just talk about the definition of being "effectively final".

```
public class LambdaTest {

    int instanceCounter = 0;

    public void method() {
        int localCounter = 0;
        instanceCounter = 5; //Re-assign instance counter so it is no longer effectively final

        Stream.of(1,2,3).forEach(elem -> instanceCounter++); //WHY DOES THE COMPILER NOT COMPLAIN HERE
        Stream.of(1,2,3).forEach(elem -> localCounter++); //Does not compile because localCounter is not effectively final
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We tend to forget that `instanceCounter` is actually `this.instanceCounter`, you are capturing `this` which is well, effectively final.  As to *why* this is needed, the answer is obviously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)

Answer (score 9):

## Why the compilation error for local variables?

The *effectively final* rule only applies to local variables and not global variables and for that reason, there is no compilation error for the first scenario as you're mutating a global variable.

If it helps *capturing* an instance variable can be seen as capturing the final local variable *this* so there is no compilation error.

## Why is there such a restriction?

The book *Java-8 in Action* has a valid explanation for this restriction, it goes as follows:

> You may be asking yourself why local variables have these
>   restrictions. First, there’s a key difference in how instance and
>   local variables are implemented behind the scenes. Instance variables
>   are stored on the heap, whereas local variables live on the stack. If
>   a lambda could access the local variable directly and the lambda were
>   used in a thread, then the thread using the lambda could try to access
>   the variable after the thread that allocated the variable had
>   deallocated it. Hence, Java implements access to a free local variable
>   as access to a copy of it rather than access to the original variable.
>
> This makes no difference if the local variable is assigned to only
>   once hence the restriction. Second, this restriction also discourages
>   typical imperative programming patterns that mutate an outer variable.